# Where to put daemon files?

Tags: filesystems, daemon

I wrote a couple daemons communicating over Unix domain sockets (raw sockets) and now I want to find the most suitable location for them on the production server. Where to put which files?

Here's what I got so far (feel free to suggest better locations):

- **Daemon binaries/executables**: no clue...  `/usr/sbin/<subdir>/`? `/usr/bin/<subdir>/`? Somewhere else?
- **Sockets:** `/var/run/<subdir>/` (no idea why but I wouldn't feel comfortable with `/tmp/`)
- **Log files**: `/var/log/<subdir>/`
- **Configuration files**: `/etc/<subdir>/`

The target OS is Ubuntu server 16.04+.

Comment: Well. Maybe rephrase the title to "Where should a daemon program put its files?". Also, it might be better to just use `syslog()` to intergrate into the server's logging system instead of directly writting a log file your self. Sockets: do systemd has this functionality to open a UDS for you or I just get it wrong? Maybe inetd or systemd can open a UDS for you then you don't have to care about socket file location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many fine resources on the standards, including https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html

I would suggest:

- **Sockets:** `/run/<subdir>/`.  That's because `/var/run` is just a sym-link to `/run` these days on Ubuntu. `/run` is the newer standard place for such things.
- **Log files**: `/var/log/<subdir>/` Correct.  Although a single log doesn't actually need a directory.  Don't forget to add an `/etc/logrotate.d` entry as well
- **Configuration files**: `/etc/<subdir>/`  Correct.  Again a single config file doesn't need a directory but it doesn't hurt.

**The binaries:**

These are tricky; there's a whole bunch of places they can exist.  Generally `bin` is for user commands, sbin is for server daemons.  Some people say `sbin` is for binaries executed only by root. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local

- Do NOT use `/bin` or `/sbin`.  Reserve these for binaries required to boot your system.
- Do use `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.  Most things on unbuntu live here although there are exceptions.  If you are properly packaging your software (into a .dpkg or similar) then definitely use `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.
- If you don't intend to package it properly and just want to manually copy it as a sys admin then `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` are more appropriate.  But this generally shouldn't be used if you are going to distribute your code to other people.
- If some of your binaries are *only ever* used by your other binaries, consider putting them under `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.  It's not uncommon for binaries to be thought of as libraries

In short, `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/bin` are most likely correct.

Comment: All directories will contain several files so I need the dirs. Since /usr/sbin/ is not allowed to have subdirs and I'm not packaging the software, I decided to use /usr/local/bin/. Thanks.

Comment: Binaries shouldn't be put in subdirectories or they will not work on the path correctly.